# Negative zero literal in golang

Tags: math, floating-point, go, ieee-754

IEEE754 supports the negative zero. 
But this code

```
a  := -0.0
fmt.Println(a, 1/a)
```

outputs

```
0 +Inf
```

where I would have expected

```
-0 -Inf
```

Other languages whose float format is based on IEEE754 let you create negative zero literals

Java :

```
float a = -0f;
System.out.printf("%f %f", a, 1/a); // outputs "-0,000000 -Infinity"
```

C# :

```
var a = -0d;
Console.WriteLine(1/a); // outputs "-Infinity"
```

Javascript :

```
​var a = -0;
console.log(a, 1/a);​ // logs "0 -Infinity"
```

But I couldn't find the equivalent in Go.

How do you write a negative zero literal in go ?

Comment: Have you tried `a := 0.0; a *= -1.0`?

Comment: No, I had only tested `a := 0.0 * -1.0`. Your code works and I'll use if without better solution. But that's not really what I'd call a literal.

Comment: Yes, not a literal. I don't know golang, so I just wanted to check this way whether it supports negative zero with ordinary operations.

Comment: Have you filed a bug against go yet?

Comment: @StephenCanon I would have asked golang-nuts before filling. But in fact this isn't needed : there is already a registered issue (see my "answer" below).

Comment: Why haven't you accepted the answer from @jnml?

Comment: @alphazero Because `1. / math.Inf(-1)` isn't a literal.

Comment: Not sure if the compiler is this smart already but that `a := 0.0; -a` case is probably the most likely to be able to be optimised down to a negative zero constant by a compiler.  It is only a little more verbose than if a literal negative zero were to be added to the language.

Comment: Note that the language explicitly defines `-0.0` as equivalent to `0.0` so changing that would not be possible at this stage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [a registered issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2196).

And it happens to give a kind of solution :

```
a := math.Copysign(0, -1)
```

It's not so bad as it obviously refers to the standard `copysign` function defined by `IEEE754`.

But this means you need to import a package and this still looks much too heavy for the (admittedly minor and rare) need.

Comment: W/o importing "math": http://play.golang.org/p/iymSJElses (and it gets inlined, I belive)

Comment: It's unfortunate that this seems to be the specified language behavior (from the discussion on the issue page), as it clearly contravenes IEEE-754 (5.12.1) "The conversions from supported formats to external character sequences [which includes source-language literals] and back that recover the original floating-point representation, shall recover zeros, infinities, and quiet NaNs, as well as non-zero finite numbers. **In particular, signs of zeros and infinities are preserved.**"

Answer (score 6):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math"
)

func main() {
        a := 1. / math.Inf(-1)
        fmt.Println(a, 1/a)
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/TeQqOq8g7F))

---

Output:

```
-0 -Inf
```

Comment: OK. It answers (hence +1). But seriously why not `a := -0.0` similarly to other languages ? Is that a bug or a "feature" ?

Comment: Mathematically -0 and 0 are equal, so I guess Go does the right thing. The signedness of 0 is, AFAIK, only a result of an underflow, not from an unary minus (like -1*0).

Comment: They're "equal" as -0==0 should give true, but in other languages (I just tested in Javascript and in Java), dividing 1 by -0 or +0 gives -Infinity or +Infinity. And this can be important.

Comment: It might be the case that Javascript and Java don't do the "right thing". K.T./R.P./M.J./... would be helpful in this, I believe. I suggest to ask again at the mailing list ;-)

Comment: Please don't compare to Javascript. JS is renowned for getting many things wrong in maths.

Comment: Maybe but the negative zero is a basic property of IEEE754 and I don't see how JS is wrong there. And it's handled in Go, the problem seem to arise from constants.

Comment: @jnml - it's not quite correct that +0 == -0 because "−0" might denote a small negative number that has been rounded to zero. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero. Note that Go is claimed to handle IEEE-754 correctly and this is one of its requirements.

Comment: @Rick-777 From the link you provide : *"According to the IEEE 754 standard, negative zero and positive zero should compare as equal with the usual (numerical) comparison operators, like the == operators of C and Java."*

Comment: As far as the comparison "==" is concerned, you are quite correct. My point is that limits and rounding issues has meant IEEE-754 needed to differentiate between +0 and -0 as an admission of the slight inexactitude of 2s-complement binary floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out this and it seems to work for me .

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    )

func main() {
    zero := float64(0)
    neg_zero := -zero
    fmt.Println(zero, neg_zero)
}
```

Though it does not work as expected when I do `neg_zer0 := - float64(0)`

Comment: That's the equivalent of the first comment I received (from Daniel Fischer). That's not a literal.