# go float zero division compiler error

Tags: go, divide-by-zero

How does this behaviour sense? wouln't it make mor sense to just print an compiler warning instead of an error?

```
func main() {
var y float64 = 0.0
var x float64 = 4.0 / y
fmt.Println(x)
}
```

+Inf

```
func main() {
var x float64 = 4.0 / 0.0
fmt.Println(x)
}
```

prog.go:9:22: division by zero

Comment: Constants aren't floats. There is no infinity constant, hence the error.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13804255/263525

Comment: Why? Division by Zero doesn't make sense. If you want infinity, type math.Inf(1).

Comment: Dividing b a literal 0 is a malformed program, thus a compiler error.

Comment: but shouldn't I be able to compile this? Rust for examle compiles with compiler warnings.

Comment: warnings are at best a code debt that all coders will have to ignore. Either it's OK, or it's an error.

Comment: so it is kind of related to the philosophy of go. That there is one way to do certain things (go fmt)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Golang numeric consts are special. They're not directly mapped to any IEEE754 float type, and they're not able to store infinities or -0 for example.

From [the documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants):

> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow. Consequently, there are no constants denoting the IEEE-754 negative zero, infinity, and not-a-number values.

This choice brings some power, as it reduces overflowing in constants:

```
var x float64 = 1e1000 / 1e999 // yes, this is 10
```

If you need an infinity value you may do

```
var x float64 = math.Inf(1)
```